# Spine.js relation, get next and previous of current lated item

Tags: spine.js

i am building a photo album app with spine mobile. I am using spine.relation to model a Album Photo relationship.

```
class Album extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'Album', ....

  @hasMany "photos", 'models/photo'


class Photo extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'Photo', ....
```

Controller:

```
class PhotosShow extends Panel
  events:
    'tap .next' : 'next'
    'tap .prev' : 'prev'

  constructor: ->
    super

    Photo.bind 'change', @render
    @active @change


  render: =>
    return unless @item
    @html require('views/photos /show')(@item)

  change: (params) ->
    @item = Asset.find(params.id)
    @render()

  next: ->
    # show next photo

  prev: ->
    # show previous photo
```

I would like to have references to next and previous photo. for the next and prev functions. whats the best way to get those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do that is to add a *weight* property to your model and use the `@findByAttribute(name, value)` method to find the model, then you can easily increase/decrease the *weight* value to get the next/previous.
Using a propery to define the order also gives you the ability to easily modify the order of your list.

Comment: i understand. i find it though over kill for what i need it for. this is a display only application at the moment. i would love to have a function which takes a Photo id and returns the next or previous Photo id in the album. Seems [backbone has this build in](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/136)

Comment: how could i get the index of the Photo in the current Album?

Comment: Is it possible to search only in the related photos with @findByAttribute()?